finding SSRS webpage login selectors for Yodeck web app script
Note: Not a web developer, just an IT admin asked to do things out-of-scope
I'm building a Yodeck web app script to log into an SSRS site. Their tool allows 'selectors' to be used to populate input fields.
https://www.yodeck.com/docs/web-scripting-engine/scripting-engine-reference/#Available_Commands
What I can see when attempting to inspect for selector
When I F12 the login webpage/prompt, there is nothing in the Dev pane and no option to inspect when I right click into the login fields, as shown in the above URL detailing the function.
Not finding actionable info from searches on 'SSRS selector', 'SSRS login API', 'find selector' and other permutation that don't involve options explored from their lit.
Are selectors not the thing used for SSRS login prompt? Is there another way to find these selectors if it is an option?
Any advice is greatly appreciated.

try with chrome, and click on inspect elements
